# Dynamically Increasing numbers in TextView Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, textview

I want to Show numbers that should increase to a particular limit dynamically.

For Example if I get a number 103. Than my textView should show 1 first and than let us say 3 than 6 than similarly increasing to 103 finally. People call it lottery style text display.

Let us say number is in num variable. than numbers should increase from (num-num) to num.

I designed Logics but if number is very large say 1 billion. than increasing/lottery effect takes too much time.

I am looking for an API where I can specify time in which I want the lottery effect to finish and final number that should be there. i guess this clarifies API requirement..

Do we have any API to do it in TextView in android???

Comment: You can use Random class to generate random numbers

Comment: why do u need an API? make a simple program for that.

Comment: lets us say number is in num variable. So numbers should increase from (num- num) to num.

Comment: You need to write your own logic for that..

Comment: yes i mean 0 to num.

Comment: Okay. And searching for lottery style text display doesn't yield any meaningful results, so I'm not sure who these people are that call it that

Comment: I designed Logics but if number is very large say 1 billion. than increasing/lottery effect takes too much time.

I am looking foe an API where i can specify time in which i want the lottery effect to finish and final number that should be there. i guess this clarifies API requirement..

Answer (score 2):

You can create simple yet random number logic for it.

- Create an array say of size 10 with random numbers eg 1,13,6,8,3,15..
- Create random number class that will give you random number between 0 to array length
- So you will get any random number within array each time
- Create addition variable, which will get incremented with the above number
- before showing the number, check if its larger than the original number
- if lesser, show the number, if larger, show the original number

You can implement any other logic, but I have sued this logic, so suggested it :)!

Comment: I designed Logics but if number is very large say 1 billion. than increasing/lottery effect takes too much time.

I am looking foe an API where i can specify time in which i want the lottery effect to finish and final number that should be there. i guess this clarifies API requirement..